# Login with OAuth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I have a .net web application (asp and c#) with login functionality (myapp), I would like to implement in a second app called secondApp a "login with myapp" button using OAuth. Do you have a good exmple with server (myapp) and client(secondApp)?
I couldn't find anything simple and working online...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the .net implementation of OpenID.  You may have to modify the code a bit to fit your purposes as it is specific to OpenID, but it is a standard OAuth implementation.

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/